# Speed up boot, timesyncd and resolved

Tags: boot

My fresh installation of 18.04 is taking 1 to 1.5 minutes to boot, while it took <10 seconds before reinstalling.

```
~$ systemd-analyze time
    Startup finished in 7.942s (firmware) + 11.813s (loader) + 5.323s (kernel) + 41.406s (userspace) = 1min 6.486s
    graphical.target reached after 41.308s in userspace


~$ systemd-analyze blame
     33.987s systemd-timesyncd.service
     33.979s systemd-resolved.service
      5.507s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      1.099s dev-sdb2.device
         ...
```

But when looking in the logs I see nothing suspicious, except that it's taking 30 seconds...

```
~$ journalctl -u systemd-timesyncd.service
    -- Reboot --
    Jan 15 12:27:18 ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting Network Time Synchronization...
    Jan 15 12:27:52 ubuntu systemd[1]: Started Network Time Synchronization.
    Jan 15 12:28:22 ubuntu systemd-timesyncd[719]: Synchronized to time server 91.189.89.199:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).


~$ journalctl -u systemd-resolved.service
    -- Reboot --
    Jan 15 12:27:18 ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting Network Name Resolution...
    Jan 15 12:27:52 ubuntu systemd-resolved[721]: Positive Trust Anchors:
    Jan 15 12:27:52 ubuntu systemd-resolved[721]: . IN DS 19036 8 2 49aac11d7b6f6446702e54a1607371607a1a41855200fd2ce1cdde32f24e8fb4
    Jan 15 12:27:52 ubuntu systemd-resolved[721]: . IN DS 20326 8 2 e06d44b80b8f1d39a95c0b0d7c65d08458e880409bbc683457104227c7f8ec8d
    Jan 15 12:27:52 ubuntu systemd-resolved[721]: Negative trust anchors: 10.in-addr.arpa 16.172.in-addr.arpa 17.172.in-addr.arpa 18.172.in-addr.arpa
    Jan 15 12:27:52 ubuntu systemd-resolved[721]: Using system hostname 'ubuntu'.
    Jan 15 12:27:52 ubuntu systemd[1]: Started Network Name Resolution.
```

Sometimes `apparmor.service` also takes ~30s which was not the case this time.

How can I speed those up?

EDIT: Changed my dns to 8.8.8.8 and now blame says this

```
 34.420s console-setup.service
 34.416s snap-vscode-74.mount
 34.381s snap-core-6130.mount
 33.962s apparmor.service
 33.927s systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
  5.400s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
  1.543s dev-sdb2.device
  1.092s keyboard-setup.service
     ...
```

However after another reboot `timesyncd` and `resolved` are still there, it appears the problem is not caused by the services as implied in the title.

Comment: I would guess there is a problem with DNS resolution, which is necessary for the time sync service. Are your DNS servers reachable?

Comment: @Jos well after the system boots I don't experience any issues, however `nmcli -t -f IP4.DNS device show eth0` shows my router address and `cat /etc/resolv.conf` has `127.0.0.53` in there, not really sure if that's an issue

Comment: @Jos Just changed my dns adresses and still experiencing this but this time with other services, I'll update the question